Implement safe app web3modal
How do should I implement https://github.com/safe-global/safe-apps-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-apps-web3modal in my app?
Documentation tells to
const modal = new SafeAppWeb3Modal(web3modalOptions);
but SafeAppWeb3Modal won't accept Web3ModalOptions as a parameter.
Once I have that object, how do I replace createWeb3Modal() with that one?
My main goal is to be able to add my app to safe "Custom app"

Adding code as requested:
'use client'
import { createWeb3Modal, defaultConfig } from '@web3modal/ethers5/react'
import { web3ModalConfig } from '@/config'

const { projectId, mainnet, metadata } = web3ModalConfig

const modal = new SafeAppWeb3Modal();

const provider = await modal.requestProvider();

const loadedAsSafeApp = await modal.isSafeApp();

createWeb3Modal({
  ethersConfig: defaultConfig({ metadata }),
  chains: [mainnet],
  projectId,
  termsConditionsUrl: 'toc',
})

export function Web3Modal({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return children
}


Could you edit your question to include the code that you are trying to make work? Thanks a lot in advance! Best, Louis

I've added some code

It seems that your app is using Next.js. In this case, as the documentation details, you should instantiate the modal inside an useEffect to avoid NextJS to process this server side where the window object does not exist.
So, inside a component (you are instantiating it at root level), you should do:
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const modal = new SafeAppWeb3Modal();
      const provider = await modal.requestProvider();
      setProvider(provider);
    })();
  }, []);

  return <>{... your code...}</>
}

Could you please try again and confirm it solved the problem? Thanks in advance 
Best, Louis
